# Doubling each number a number of times as specify by the user

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to hadoop and I am learning by using few examples. I am currently trying to pass a file with random integers on it. For each and every number i want it to be double base on the number specify by the user at runtime.

3536    5806    2545    249 485 5467    1162    8941    962 6457
665 6754    889 5159    3161    5401    704 4897    135 907
8111    1059    4971    5195    3031    630 6265    827 5882    9358
9212    9540    676 3191    4995    8401    9857    4884    8002    3701
931 875 6427    6945    5483    545 4322    5120    1694    2540
9039    5524    872 840 8730    4756    2855    718 6612    4125

Above is the file sample.

For example when the user specify at runtime

```
 jar ~/dissertation/workspace/TestHadoop/src/DoubleNum.jar DoubleNum Integer Output 3
```

the output for say the first line will be 
3536 * 8    5806* 8 2545* 8 249* 8  485* 8  5467* 8 1162* 8 8941* 8 962* 8  6457* 8

Because for each iteration the number will be double so for 3 iterations it will be 2^3. How can I achieve this using mapreduce?

Comment: are you sure mapreduce is the right thing for this task?

Comment: @Thomas Jungblut I just want to implement it on MapReduce. The whole point is I just want to see how I can iterating a sub skeleton like a map a number of times. iter(Map, 4) for it to run the mapper 4 times in parallel but the output of the firt map will be pass as input to the second.

Answer (score 0):

For chaining one job into the next, check out:
[Chaining multiple MapReduce jobs in Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499585/chaining-multiple-mapreduce-jobs-in-hadoop)

Also, this may be a good time to learn about sequence files, as they provide an efficient way of passing data from one map/reduce job to another.

As for your particular problem, you don't need reducers here, so make it map-only by setting the number of reducers to zero. Sending the output to reducers will only incur extra network overhead. (However, be careful about the number of files you create over time, eventually the NameNode will not appreciate it. Each mapper will create one file.)

I understand that you are trying to use this as an example of perhaps something more complex... but in this case you can use a common optimization technique: If you find yourself wanting to chain one mapper-only task into another map/reduce job, you can squash the two mappers together. For example, instead of multiplying by 2, then 2 gain, the 2 again, why not just multiply by 2 and by 2 and by in the same mapper? Basically, if all your operations are independent on one number or line, you can apply the iterations within the same mapper, per record. This will reduce the amount of overhead significantly.

Comment: Chaining will waiting for the first map to run and then later run another map on the output of the previous map?

What I exactly want to do is for example. It will be easier to use a sketch of the Mapper class.

Comment: Basically I just want the map function to be iterating a number of times. The above example is only to simplify the explanation but the operations within the map could be anything.