# Hadoop. Restart Map

Tags: hadoop

After 36 hours of working Hadoop 1.0.3 said:

```
INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 42% reduce 0%
     mapred.JobClient: Job Failed: # of failed Map Tasks exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount: 1. 
     java.io.IOException: Job failed!
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1265)
```

and stopped.

Is it possible to restart Hadoop jobs not from the very beginning (map 0%  reduce 0%) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a good way to restart a failed job. A couple of things to keep in mind:

1. looks like your in mapred config [mapreduce.map.maxattempts=1]  and the default is typically 4

   ```
   mapred.JobClient: Job Failed: # of failed Map Tasks 
   exceeded allowed limit. FailedCount: 1.
   ```
2. You would typically want to understand why it failed. (not sure from your post if you identified the issue)

It may have failed for a bogus reason and you can implement this exception into your mapreduce program by providing [failure traps](http://docs.cascading.org/cascading/2.1/userguide/html/ch07s03.html). You can implement that same concept using the Hadoop API.

Check out this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9742235/1515370