# Hierarchical MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cluster-computing

I was wondering if it is possible to define a Hierarchical MapReduce job?. 
In other words I would like to have a map-reduce job, that in the mapper phase will call a different MapReduce job. Is it possible? Do you have any recommendations how to do it?

I want to do it in order to have additional level of parallelism/distribution in my program.
Thanks,
Arik.

Answer (score 2):

[Hadoop definitive guide book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010388.do) contains lot of recipes related to MapReduce job chaining including sample code and detailed explanation. Especially chapter called like 'advanced API usage' or something near it.

I personally succeeded with replacement of complex map-reduce job with several HBase tables used as sources with handmade `TableInputFormat` extension. The result was input format which combines source data with minimal reduction so job was transformed to single mapper step. So I recommend you to look in this direction too.

Comment: Roman, the reason I removed that link is because it is to a pirated version of the ebook. We do not allow links like that here. If you want to link to it, do so to O'Reilly's legitimate site.

Comment: Their "sample" was 647 pages long and contained the original O'Reilly formatting, as well as every page from every chapter I checked. That site is a known host of bootleg material like this, so we've scrubbed all links to it here.

Answer (score 1):

You should try [Cascading](http://www.cascading.org/). It allows you to define pretty complex jobs with multiple steps.

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for a "native" hadoop solution for this task/ Any suggestions?

Comment: Native meaning no external libraries? Just wait until the job is done and submit a new one.

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499585/chaining-multiple-mapreduce-jobs-in-hadoop

Comment: Hi, Regarding "native" this is what I meant. Regarding the other part this is not what I meant. I want to run the second mapreduce job for every record I read in the mapper of the first mapreduce job

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need oozie tool. Oozie helps in defining workflows using an xml file.