# Sort in order of value Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to sort out out in order of value and trying to run two 
mappers and reducers, but when the second job starts it fails and says:

> 14/12/21 18:43:35 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation:
>   PriviledgedActionException as:cloudera (auth:SIMPLE)
>   cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output
>   directory
>   hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/cloudera/wordcount/output
>   already exists Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory
>   hdfs://localhost.localdomain:8020/user/cloudera/wordcount/output
>   already exists

Here is my code:

```
package org.myorg;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;

public class WordCount {

public static class Map extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
            output.collect(word, one);
        }
    }
}

public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        int sum = 0;
        while (values.hasNext()) {
            sum += values.next().get();
        }
        output.collect(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
}

class Map1 extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<Object, Text, IntWritable, Text> {

    public void map(Object key, Text value, OutputCollector<IntWritable, Text> collector, Reporter arg3) throws IOException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        {
            int number = 999;
            String word = "empty";

            if (stringTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String str0 = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
                word = str0.trim();
            }

            if (stringTokenizer.hasMoreElements()) {
                String str1 = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
                number = Integer.parseInt(str1.trim());
            }
            collector.collect(new IntWritable(number), new Text(word));
        }

    }

}

class Reduce1 extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<IntWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {

    public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<IntWritable, Text> arg2, Reporter arg3) throws IOException {
        while ((values.hasNext())) {
            arg2.collect(key, values.next());
        }
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
    conf.setJobName("wordCount");

    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path("wordcount/output"));

//JobClient.runJob(conf);
    //------------------------------------------------------------------
    JobConf conf2 = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
    conf2.setJobName("WordCount1");

    conf2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf2.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    conf2.setMapperClass(Map1.class);
    conf2.setCombinerClass(Reduce1.class);
    conf2.setReducerClass(Reduce1.class);

    conf2.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
    conf2.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf2, new Path("wordcount/output/part-00000"));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf2, new Path(args[1]));

    Job job1 = new Job(conf);
    Job job2 = new Job(conf2);

    job1.submit();
if (job1.waitForCompletion(true)) {
    job2.submit();
    job2.waitForCompletion(true);
    }

   }
 }
```

I have tried changing the path a few times even creating a new direct called tmp but no luck.

Current Error Message :

```
    14/12/21 19:58:12 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201412211623_0042
    14/12/21 19:58:13 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
    14/12/21 19:58:35 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :      attempt_201412211623_0042_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.ja
14/12/21 19:58:35 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201412211623_0042_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:109)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:413)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:332)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:268)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1438)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:262)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.ja
14/12/21 19:58:54 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201412211623_0042_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
```

Comment: i have tried changing the path afew times even creating a new direct called tmp but no luck

Comment: how you are passing input and output path?

Comment: sorry i dont get what you mean am really bad at this hadoop stuff, like really bad ><

Comment: all i know is that the output of the first map-reduce should be the input of the second map reduce but

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use new API

This example is based on new API

```
public class ChainJobs extends Configured implements Tool {

 private static final String OUTPUT_PATH = "intermediate_output";

 @Override
 public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
  /*
   * Job 1
   */
  Configuration conf = getConf();
  FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
  Job job = new Job(conf, "Job1");
  job.setJarByClass(ChainJobs.class);

  job.setMapperClass(MyMapper1.class);
  job.setReducerClass(MyReducer1.class);

  job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
  job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

  job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
  job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

  TextInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
  TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(OUTPUT_PATH));

  job.waitForCompletion(true);

  /*
   * Job 2
   */
  Configuration conf2 = getConf();
  Job job2 = new Job(conf2, "Job 2");
  job2.setJarByClass(ChainJobs.class);

  job2.setMapperClass(MyMapper2.class);
  job2.setReducerClass(MyReducer2.class);

  job2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
  job2.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

  job2.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
  job2.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

  TextInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, new Path(OUTPUT_PATH));
  TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, new Path(args[1]));

  return job2.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
 }
```

`private static final String OUTPUT_PATH = "intermediate_output";` is defined for 1st jobs output and it will be the input to second job.

Refer [this](http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/04/chaining-jobs-in-hadoop-mapreduce.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hope that link helped u :)

Answer (score 0):

All the error says is the `wordcount/output` directory already exists. I see that you hard coded the value for the output directory for the first MR job (`FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path("wordcount/output"));`).

If you have this directory (`output`) already existing the job will fail as it prevents you from overriding stuff. Try removing that directory and running the job with new directory.

Comment: when i change the directories like this 
Job1:
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path("tmp"));
Job2:
       FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf2, new Path("tmp/part-00000"));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf2, new Path(args[1]));

I get an error that says: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object

Comment: Is the ` FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf2, new Path(args[1]));` args[1] also the same as `tmp` in the above case ...

Comment: so i should make a completly new directory like temp/tempfiles ? and store the first output there ?

Comment: the system creates that for you once running the job. You just need to specify the directory. Say you specify `outputTemp`, don't create it it will be created once the output needs to be populated.

Comment: still not getting anything that same error. i really have no clue anymore. 
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object
Thank you for the help tho

Comment: You still get the `FileAlreadyExistsException` or is it a new exception

Comment: No getting a new exception now saying 
"java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in configuring object"

Comment: Can you paste the full error message in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2 different reducers job may be trying to write at same location. In hdfs we can not update or overwrite. You need to delete exiting file, dir location if you want to write at same location again.

Following are some useful references

[chaining-multiple-mapreduce-jobs-in-hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499585/chaining-multiple-mapreduce-jobs-in-hadoop)

[job chaining](https://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html#chaining)