# Hadoop global variable with streaming

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I understand that i can give some global value to my mappers via the Job and the Configuration.

But how can i do that using Hadoop Streaming(Python in my case)?

What is the right way?

Comment: What are you using to launch your jobs (Mesos, SLURM)?

Comment: I'm not familiar with both..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [docs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/streaming.html) you can specify a command line option (`-cmdenv name=value`) to set environment variables on each distributed machine that you can then use in your mappers/reducers:

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop  jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-streaming.jar \
    -input input.txt \
    -output output.txt \
    -mapper mapper.py \
    -reducer reducer.py \
    -file mapper.py \
    -file reducer.py \
    -cmdenv MY_PARAM=thing_I_need
```

Comment: is that the only way? it looks 'ugly'.
Anyway, how do i access to that variable in my python code?

Comment: Hadoop manages all of the distribution for you so this simply sets up environment variables on each machine it runs on. You could also make a call over the network to some internal and static location but this is a no-no because it is expensive. Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/how-to-access-environment-variables-from-python) regarding accessing your environment variable.